# Does maven make the need for writing test suites obsolete?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit, maven-3

As maven follows convention over configuration approach. All the test cases are located in the test folder in the project structure. So maven know's that these are test case classes and runs them automatically.
So does this make unnecessary to write explicit test suite classes and aggregate  test results through developer written code.
Is maven acting as a test suite management tool too.

Comment: JUnit predates Maven by a number of years.  So the answer is No.  Writing custom tests suite (frameworks) was obsolete before Maven came along.

Answer (score 2):

Maven has nothing much to do with it. All the common build tools can search a folder for JUnit or TestNG tests. Suites are thus not needed unless you need some unusual configuration applied over a collection of tests.

Comment: that's it... needed some confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Maven mostly provides a test execution environment and a convention as to how test artifacts are organized in a file system. Beyond that, the manner of tests and their structure depends on the project/code under test and what goals are to be achieved.

For the most part, test suites are just logical collections of test classes, which in turn define one or more test methods; though they can have more complex structures. Different types of tests focus on different aspects and test suites can be used to organize unit and functional tests, integration tests, compliance tests, performance and nonfunctional tests, etc. into their own separate collections that can be invoked when necessary.

Test suites allow these type of tests to be easily switch in and out as needed via test environments such as those provided by Maven or an IDE. For example, there is rarely a need to run performance tests or other higher-level tests until functional tests pass. Furthermore, the responsibility for running different tests may be assigned to different people.

Another use of test suites is for constructing and deconstructing "expensive" test environments. Test suites allow setting up an environment once, before all test classes and their methods are executed; thereafter, deconstructing the environment once completed.

This approach is no different than using `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotated methods in test classes to set up environments for all tests  therein. The only difference is that test suites work with a collection of test classes, whereas the latter work with a collection of test methods in a given class.

In sum, test suites definitely have their uses and depend upon the complexity of a project or set of projects. Someone writing a Spigot plugin or a simple application would rarely use test suites; however, a project member of an enterprise level application would most likely use some form of them. The chances of using test suites increase as development efforts migrate from low-level component design through, package, library, and application design, up to an beyond systems-of-systems design.